# Adding specific point info in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I'm plotting the magnitude and phase response of a notch filter I designed and I need to mark the cutoff frequencies as well as the notch frequency point. I'd like to show the same information that shows up if you click on a plot. Is there a way to force MATLAB to show boxes like the one that shows up if you click on a point?

I have attached an image showing what I mean. I'd like to get a box like that at specific frequency points that I choose.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can actually be done a little more reliably and robustly using some undocumented features of the data cursor ([info](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/controlling-plot-data-tips)). First we will get the figure's underlying `datacursormode` and then use that to add and move datatips (like the one in your figure).

```
fig = figure();

% Plot some fake data for now
xdata = linspace(0, 2*pi, 100);
ydata = sin(xdata);

hLine = plot(xdata, ydata);

% Get the datacursormode of the current figure and enable it
cursorMode = datacursormode(gcf);
set(cursorMode, 'enable','on')
```

Now that we have the `datacursormode` object, we can use it to add some new datatips.

```
datatip = cursorMode.createDatatip(handle(hLine));
% X,Y position at which to place the datatip
set(datatip, 'Position', [xdata(50), ydata(50)]);
```

[image]

We can move this datatip again if we want.

```
set(datatip, 'Position', [xdata(1), ydata(1)]);
```

The really nice thing, is that using the `cursorMode` object we can also create *more* datatips

```
datatip2 = cursorMode.createDatatip(handle(hLine));
set(datatip2, 'Position', [xdata(75), ydata(75)])
```

[image]

By combining this information with your own plots and data, you should be able to automatically place the datatips that you need reliably.

Answer (score 1):

Here an example I built for an exponential function:

```
clear all

figure
f = plot(exp(1:10));

datacursormode on

% get the handle of the data cursor 
hdc = get(gcf,'WindowButtonDownFcn');
dcm = hdc{3}{2};


props.Position = [min(exp(1:10)) log(min(f)) 1];

dcm.createDatatip(f,props);
```

But you have to generalize the definition of the coordiates for the cursor to your case.